# How to access safeArea insets while the parent view used IgnoringSafeArea()

Tags: swiftui, safearea

As you can see the picture I want to place the search bar exactly to the top of the `safeArea` but the `proxy.safeAreaInsets` has not the proper value because in the `PreviewProvider` the parent uses `edgesIgnoringSafeArea`.

what can I do ? is there any way to access safeAreaInsets?

```
struct FindView: View {
  
  // MARK: -  Properties
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: FindViewModel
  
  init(viewModel: FindViewModel){
    self.viewModel = viewModel

  }
  
  var body: some View {
 
      GeometryReader { proxy in
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true, content: {
          VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8){
             SearchBar()
              .frame(height: 48, alignment: .center)
              .padding(.all, 16)
              
            
            Text("Categories")
              .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
              .font(.system(size: 21))
              .padding(.all, 16)
              
          }.frame(width: proxy.size.width)
        })
      }
  }
}

struct FindView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .center, content: {
      Rectangle().foregroundColor(.red)
      FindView(viewModel: FindViewModel())
    }).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
  }
}
```

[image: Preview of the code]

Answer (score 2):

simple way;

```
     struct test: View {
          var body: some View {
              VStack{
                Text("Your view comes here")
                Spacer()
              }
               .frame(minWidth:0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0,maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
               .padding(.top,UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 40)
               .background(Color.red)
               .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` only to the rectangle, not to the ZStack. This way, only it should fill the screen, while everything else remains in place.

Then, to make it so that the `FindView` fills the screen (respecting safe area), you need make its frame extend with `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)`

---

Code sample:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Text("This should respect the safe area")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
        }
    }
}
```